# Error starting machine: Error in driver during machine start: exit status 1

Tags: openshift

I am trying to setup Red Hat OpenShift on my Window 10.

I have completed the `crc setup`

```
C:\Program Files\Red Hat OpenShift Local>crc setup
INFO Using bundle path C:\Users\xxx\.crc\cache\crc_hyperv_4.13.0_amd64.crcbundle
INFO Checking minimum RAM requirements
INFO Checking if current user is in crc-users and Hyper-V admins group
INFO Checking if CRC bundle is extracted in '$HOME/.crc'
INFO Checking if C:\Users\xxx\.crc\cache\crc_hyperv_4.13.0_amd64.crcbundle exists
INFO Checking if the daemon task is installed
INFO Checking if the daemon task is running
INFO Checking admin helper service is running
Your system is correctly setup for using CRC. Use 'crc start' to start the instance
```

But when I run `crc start`, it says `Error starting machine: Error in driver during machine start: exit status 1`

```
C:\Program Files\Red Hat OpenShift Local>crc start
INFO Checking minimum RAM requirements
INFO Checking if running in a shell with administrator rights
INFO Checking Windows release
INFO Checking Windows edition
INFO Checking if Hyper-V is installed and operational
INFO Checking if Hyper-V service is enabled
INFO Checking if crc-users group exists
INFO Checking if current user is in crc-users and Hyper-V admins group
INFO Checking if vsock is correctly configured
INFO Checking if the daemon task is installed
INFO Checking if the daemon task is running
INFO Checking admin helper service is running
INFO Loading bundle: crc_hyperv_4.13.0_amd64...
INFO Starting CRC VM for openshift 4.13.0...
Error starting machine: Error in driver during machine start: exit status 1
```

I try to search for the logs to troubleshoot but found none.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

mostly this would be an issue with the resources use the following command
crc start --log-level debug
if it returned that it couldn't get the needed memory then you would need to install more memory or empty what you already have by closing apps such as Chrome